# How to control same thread interference in application?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, quartz-scheduler

HI Friend,
              I am facing a critical issue with current developing. Actually i am using Quartz library to schedule my tasks in this application. and  i have fix a specific time to call a specific method. But some time , if method takes more execution time than already fixed time then this method is being called again so my all processing execute repeatedly. I have tried to synchronized keyword but it is not working.

**I am using code schedule My Task -**

```
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;


public class BrainScheluder {
public BrainScheluder()
{       
     try {
            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
            Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

            // Start scheduler here
            scheduler.start();

         // define the job and tie it to our BrainJob class
            JobDetail job = newJob(BrainJob.class)
                .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .build();

            // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 60 seconds
            Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(30)
                        .repeatForever())
                .build();

            // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

         // End scheduler here
            //scheduler.shutdown();

        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
 }
```

**And I am Using Code Perform My Work -**

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

 import org.quartz.Job; 
 import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
 import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
  import com.my.Vi;


  public class BrainJob implements Job {
    Vi v = null;
   public BrainJob() {
     v= new Vi();
    }

    public synchronized void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
      throws JobExecutionException
    {

       v.myWork();
   }
   }
```

The method of myWork Of Vi class is used to process some data whenever data is a large size then this function is being called repeatedly. and whenever data is not a large size then this function is being called nicely.

So

can we control myWork() method calling according to our processing time requirement. i mean that can we synchronized myWork() method ? here.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at marking Brainjob with this annotation `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`? See: this [link](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html)

Comment: @Michael Petch, Sir i use this library first time so i think didn't use described concept(@DisallowConcurrentExecution) by you. please suggest me how to use it.

Comment: Just a side note:  If an exception is thrown within the constructor for your BrainScheduler, the only indication will be a stack trace printed to standard error.  As far as the calling code will know, the constructor will appear to have completed normally.  The calling code will not have any way to know that the BrainJob is not running.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, you could set a flag somewhere when `myWork()` starts (session, or context of some sort, database, it depends on other things you are using), and then before each execution check the status of that flag. If the method has not finished its work, just don't start it again. Once it finishes, reset the flag, and when next scheduled time comes it will execute normally as it should.